# How can I fetch from an JSON file and display some pictures

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm try to display multiple pictures from fetched JSON data in to DOM how can I perform this task efficient way ?
(just using pure JS)

```js
async function Data(){
    
    const response = await fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/whichbuffer/c835320d7dcf9899a22890b0a3589d88/raw/97f9bb3d4e0c9d558cc5184eb21a12831895dfa4/IMDB.json');
    const data = await response.json(); 
    console.log(data.Contents);
    
    for(let i=0;i<data.Contents.length;i++){
        document.getElementById('Title').innerHTML +=("<br>" + data.Contents[i].Title + "<br>")
       document.getElementById('img').src += (data.Contents[i].Poster)
    }
}

Data().catch(error => {
    console.log("error!");
    console.error(error);
});
```

```html
<img src="" id="img">
<p id="Title"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will append a `<li>` for each object in the array to the `<ul>`.

```js
const list = document.getElementById("imglist")

async function Data() {
    //Fetch the JSON
    const response = await fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/whichbuffer/c835320d7dcf9899a22890b0a3589d88/raw/97f9bb3d4e0c9d558cc5184eb21a12831895dfa4/IMDB.json');
    const data = await response.json(); 
    
    //Loop over the fetched array
    for(let i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++){
        //Create the `<li>`
        const li = document.createElement("li")
        
        //Create the `<p>` for the title and add it to the `<li>`
        const p = document.createElement("p")
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.Contents[i].Title))
        li.appendChild(p)
        
        //Create the `<img>` for the poster and add it to the `<li>`
        const img = document.createElement("img")
        img.src = data.Contents[i].Poster
        li.appendChild(img)
        
        //Add the `<li>` to the list
        list.appendChild(li)
    }
}

Data().catch(error => {
    console.log("error!");
    console.error(error);
});
```

```html
<ul id="imglist"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you dump your XHR Request /Json Response ?

Comment: yes I can you can see If you uncomment console.log(data.Contents)